# Could not find method plugins() for arguments

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when i start my project android studio with the emulator i got this message

[image: this is the error picture]

i added firebase options my project and then i started to get that message. it gives me plugins() error. what can i do to solve this error.

Comment: Please replace the screenshot of the error message in your question with a text block with the error message as text. Images are not searchable and it is unlikely relevant people will find this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to delete the android folder, and recreate it using `flutter create . --platforms=android`, then using flutterfire-cli tool to import it correctly.

It seems you broke the `build.gradle` file and without looking at your android/ folder's files it's not clear immediately what's wrong